# In Spring, can I make a single field in @RequestBody optional?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a route like:

```
@PostMapping("/")
public void sendNotification(@RequestBody PostBody postBody){...}
```

And the fields in `PostBody` class are:

```
public class PostBody {
    private String type;
    private String payload;
    private String recipients;
    private String callerId;
```

I am wondering, can I make one or more of these fields optional, but not all of them?

I guess if I use `(require = false)`, all fields will be optional, is that right?

Then is there anyway to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use standard Validation annotations for this. Just annotate the mandatory fields with `@NotNull` or `@NotEmpty`, and add `@Valid` to your request body parameter:

```
@PostMapping("/")
public void sendNotification(@Valid @RequestBody PostBody postBody){...}

public class PostBody {
    @NotEmpty private String type; // String must be non-null and contain at least one character
    @NotNull private String payload; // fails on null but not on ""
    private String recipients; // allows null or "" or any value
    private String callerId;
}
```

Comment: May I know which dependency should I add? Is it Thymeleaf? It seems not.

Comment: @powerseed it is `spring-boot-starter-validation`

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to request for a Map object in method's signature, i.e. `@RequestBody Map<String, String> json` and then to validate this object on my own, i.e.

```
String type = json.getOrDefault("type", null);

if (type==null)
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
```

If you want to use it, remember to change the method's return type.